# Mathematica won't find SerialIO package

Tags: macos, serial-port, wolfram-mathematica, nxt

I'm following a [guide](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/2013/03/controlling-robots-built-with-the-lego-mindstorms-nxt-brick/#Raguet-Schofield) from The Mathematica Journal that describes how to use Mathematica with the Lego Mindstorms NXT. I have some trouble getting started and got stuck with the [SerialIO](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/5726/) package.

I use Mac OSX and I have installed the package to:

```
/Applications/Mathematica.app/AddOns/ExtraPackages/SerialIO/
```

The command **Needs["SerialIO`"]** gives me the following error message:

```
LinkOpen::linke: Could not find MathLink executable.
```

And trying

```
SetDirectory[FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "AddOns", "ExtraPackages", "SerialIO", $SystemID}]];
```

Does not help either, it gives:

```
SetDirectory::cdir: Cannot set current directory to /Applications/Mathematica.app/AddOns/ExtraPackages/SerialIO/MacOSX-x86-64.
```

There seem to be some problem with the alias/symbolic link in the SerialIO folder. By default they pointed to an absolute directory on the machine that this library was built on:

```
MacOSX-x86-64 -> /Files/schofield/Packages/SerialIO/Build/Mac/build/Deployment/Package/SerialIO/MacOSX
```

I tried deleting the alias and creating a symbolic link in the terminal:

```
ln -s MacOSX MacOSX-x86-64
```

Running the **SetDirectory** command again result in... no result, so I guess thats good. The commands seem to have been loaded as when typing *Serial* it want to autocomplete to **SerialOpen** etc.

However, using the command **mybrick = SerialOpen["name of serial port"]** does not put the NXT in connected mode (<> on NXT display). Does anyone else got it to work?

Comment: See this question for answer: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23826/problem-with-serialio-package-and-lego-nxt

Answer (score 4):

There was a problem in SerialIO in combination with Mathematica9. After some correspondence in may 2013, Wolfram Support find the problem and updated SerialIO for me. It seems logical that they also update SerialIO on their site. Please have a try and download SerialIO again and update. My OS is MaxOSX.